Doxygen reference files in mainpage
I am using Doxygen 1.10.0 for C, where each source file is basically a module.
Is it possible to reference/list all source files automatically inside the "mainpage" similar how it looks like in the Files > Files List page?
So that this table would also be present in the "Main Page"

In addition, would it also be possible to list all functions as well on the mainpage for each source file?

Which version of doxygen are you using? Which settings do you use different from the default settings (i.e. the result of doxygen -c Doxyfile). Cqn you please add a small example to the question (and maybe a sketch of what you want to accomplish)?

At the moment I don't see a possibility to add all files to the mainpage (btw. did you have a look at GENERATE_TREEVIEW)
